# Why does commenting require reputation when answering a question does not?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment)

Is there any reason unregistered users (or users without rep) can answer a question but can't add comments?

I ask because, for example, [a question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008245/flex-whats-the-difference-between-an-mxml-component-and-an-mxml-module/2448734#2448734) has one (correct and helpful) answer, and three "thanks, that helped me too" "answers".

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment

Comment: @Shog - not really a duplicate. That one's marked "status completed" on the basis of Jeff's answer about being able to comment on answers to *your own* question. This post is about others posting answers to the OPs question because they can't comment.

Comment: The correct answer is that they should just vote up the answer that helped them (and possibly the question). There's really no need to post "me too" or "thanks" as an answer. And before everyone jumps on me I know they are only trying to be polite.

Comment: @ChrisF: Uh, if that's why Jeff marked it as "status-complete" then he could just as well mark this one the same: both are about questions where folks *other than the OP* showed up and started leaving comments in answers - just look at the examples linked to!

Comment: @Chr: What's wrong with writing "the correct answer" and posting it as comment? Do you just make a point? That you have enough rep to comment? YOU FAILED! POST AN ANSWER, SUCKER!

Comment: @John, you are not supposed to answer duplicate questions

Comment: @Dow: Chris said, it wasn't a duplicate and it wasn't closed when he wrote his comment.

Comment: @Chris, if you have 1 rep then you can't vote.

Comment: @mmyers - D'oh - forgot that! But the vote threshold (15) is lower than the comment threshold (50)

Comment: The short-short version is that comments (on questions other than you own) are unnecessary to the core mission of the site and are subject to fewer mechanism for community control than questions and answers. So you have to show a minimum degree of trustworthiness before you get to play.

Comment: @dmckee - thanks, that makes a lot of sense.