# General thoughts on Stack Exchange: Please do something

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, comments, down-votes

I just want to get this straight. On Stack Exchange, there are reputation-walls everywhere.

1. Why do I need enough reputation to comment? This forces me to make an answer, which always gets downvoted because it doesn't have enough info. I wanted to make a comment, but it's impossible as requires 50 reps.
2. Just yesterday, I gave a resource link to someone, but it got downvoted. And what am I told? "Go discuss about this system in Meta". But the problem is I couldn't (You need 5 rep to ask here). So I had to come over here, to the Meta Stack Exchange, just to ask this. And just as I was hoping for the better, I get limited posting.
3. Why can other people edit my own post when it is my question? I understand when it fixed spelling/simple thing, but this allows people to change the question itself. It should at least be reviewed by the Owner of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does commenting require reputation when answering a question does not?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42331/), see also [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/), and basically everything in the Linked and Related sidebars of those two. For the meta requirement, see [
Can we revisit the reputation minimum to post on a site's Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238568/226203) and [Meta participation privilege should require 5 rep or… something else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238538/226203)

Comment: Its not a duplicate. Please read the whole thing, and not just look at the title.

Comment: Sorry, had some more links to track down for the rest of that comment. [How does a new user begin using Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188611/226203) may also be of help, or maybe [How do you get more than 1 reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198240/226203). It might not be precisely a duplicate of any of those, but it's very much a duplicate overall.

Comment: You have asked too many questions in one to easily answer you. All the things you ask here have been discussed before, you should do some searches, and use the links @BillyMailman provided.

Comment: Where did nicaels comments on this question go????? @nicael

Comment: A mod removed them, because they weren't appropriate for this question.

Comment: Hmm......You should be a mod @nicael. You should apply if you haven't. Also, is there some sort of chat between 2 users only?

Comment: I can't talk there. It says i need 20 rep on SO, which I have

Comment: Hey @nicael I can't talk...It says i don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 21):

The purpose of these sites is to create Answers for Questions. Q&A isn't the only important thing in life, but it *is* important enough that we built all these sites for that express purpose.

Comments, voting, etc. all exist merely to further that core purpose. We see very little value in encouraging commentary outside of areas that directly contribute to better questions or better answers... And even then, it's preferable if you can submit an edit that *directly* improves either.

With this in mind, surely it makes sense that the three actions which require no reputation are:

- Asking questions
- Answering questions
- Editing existing questions or answers

All of those directly contribute to the core goals of these sites. You don't *have* to do any of them, but if you're interested in participating then *start with one of those activities*. Once you've been around for a while and seen how your own questions, answers and edits are treated, you'll come to appreciate how little noise there is, and how commentary is *usually* reserved for things you - **as an author** - actually want to see. How unlike *every other site on The Internet*, comment threads do not normally overwhelm all other forms of feedback, drowning out useful information and punishing those who create useful documents by wasting their time day-in day-out for the rest of eternity.

But until then, just trust me: begin by writing useful answers or insightful questions. The rest will follow.

Answer (score 9):

The limit on comments is effectively an anti-spam mechanism since questions and answers are mostly community moderated. Comments aren't and they are not that visible as questions/answers. And the reputation barriers are very easy to overcome. If you suggest two edits which get approved, you already have 5 reputation, which is enough to participate in Meta.

It isn't hard to participate. It is hard to do so without knowing (and first reading and understanding) the site rules. Since SO/SE is very different from your regular discussion board and is a lot harsher on the rules, it might come of rude, but it isn't.

I am glad you took the time to post here, and I hope this won't bring you down. We all started at 1, so we know how hard it is to get started, but I know you can.

Comment: This is my problem. This post already has -1. Sure I can get started.....sure.....I have knowledge in 9 programming languages, and host 5 websites, but everything I have done so far, has been marked down, 0, or I deleted because it was way too low. Its easy enough to say "We all started there" but you are not in my position right now. I am seriously considering deleting my account on SO, SE.

Comment: But why? People didn't like your answers, or your answers weren't according to the rules. If you answer with a comment, yes, you will get down-voted. Write a fully fledged answer and I am sure you will see the positive results of it.

Comment: I can't even comment.......

Comment: So, just wait until the question is clear enough to answer.

Comment: I currently have a question limit. It's working great now isn't it? Let me see: I cant ask, cant comment, cant vote on ANYTHING, and in order to vote, I have tried to answer questions, but they were down voted, by moderators in fact. There is only a single person that has helped so far, but that question is still at 0.

Comment: So what moderator down-voted you? How do you know? Voting is anonymous...

Comment: Because he also commented...

Comment: So who cares? Even if he did, why care? He is just a user that judged the usefulness of your post. And it wasn't useful (according to that user).

Comment: I can't say much else. I am very disappointed with the site now. And yes, I do care. It affects reputation, which in turn limits pretty much everything. I AM considering deleting my user, it has nothing beneficial so far. Even now, I edited my post, but someone took the whole edit out. (Yes I know you did)

Comment: So a user trying to improve your post shouldn't do anything? **Don't you see we are trying to be helpful here?**

Comment: Helpful??????? Ok, this has gone too far. All I can currently do is post answers that say "You might get banned" when writing. Literally nothing else. I'm serious.

Comment: @phi I read your comments and I am glad you took some advice to heart. Good work!

Answer (score 2):

Not every question requires clarification and not any questions can be answered only with links.

There're plenty of questions from newbies or not really advanced users, and it's possible to answer them pretty easily. Do mind that typically it's disliked by the community if you answer the duplicate questions, so it's encouraged to check if the question has already been answered before.

As you seem to know 9 programming languages, it's pretty simple to see the questions asked only in those tags. Use [Site search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for this purpose (e.g. to search for java and c++ questions, enter `[java] or [c++]`). Once you reach 50 rep (only on SO, the other sites require 1 rep, i.e. nothing to earn), you get instantly notified about new questions (live updates), this provides you with an ability to get the new questions as fast as possible.

> [image]

Until 50 rep, you'll have to reload the page to see the new questions.

Also, as for the edits: I don't think anything bad happens when anyone can edit your question. Because it's not actually anyone - it requires 2000 rep for the editor to have their edits to go through instantly, so don't worry some inexperienced user messes up with your question :) (btw: adding "edit:" is discouraged, because any edits can be seen via [revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/269154/revisions))

Comment: Then why does every single edit say EDIT: on other questions?

Comment: It doesn't. And if so, feel free to edit it out. You will get 2 reputation if that edit is approved :) You see how easy this is?

Comment: @Philipposs this happens when they are not experienced enough to know that every edit is recorded and intentionally add "edit:" - this doesn't happen with any suggested edit automatically though.

Comment: Fixed the "EDIT" message. Thanks for that

Comment: Nicael BTW have you reported "1 new questions" in your screenshot already? It's been some time since I last read your bug reports. :P

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Well, you seem to underestimate me :D https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309923/pluralizations11-bugs-ons-thes-homepages (it's just SO specific, so I reported on MSO)

Comment: Oh. *All hail Nicael*