# Does the SE search engine search the term among comments and answers?

Tags: discussion, search

Does the SE search engine search the term among comments and answers, or only questions? For example I want to find a comment and I remember some words of it, is there a way to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to find it by creating a query on data.stackexchange.com. For example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62213/search-comments

Answer (score 3):

There's not a way to search for what you're after yet.  The search engine doesn't index comments or wikis...at this time.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the (hidden) [search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/search)

> is:answer apples oranges

will search for "apples" or "oranges" in answers only.

I don't think there's one for comments.