# Correct answer became incorrect after a question edit, what now?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

Imagine there's a question.

And there is an answer - a correct one, getting upvotes.

OP edits his question, because he forgot to specify a detail which now renders the answer incorrect. OP also points out his edit in the answer's comments.

There is a second answer. A correct one, accepted, didn't get a single upvote.

---

In the end, there's a question with a correct and accepted answer, and an incorrect, but upvoted one. Everything seems fine, I am just curious about what to do now? Is it ok to downvote the previously correct answer? Should I edit it (after some time, ofc) to point out that it is no longer true so it won't confuse anyone? Should I leave it to its own life?

Comment: Link to example(s) please.

Comment: [This.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403637/xpath-match-whole-word-using-matches-function-with-case-insensitive-flag/) Note that two last two answers appeared even after.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Downvoting an answer which was given in good faith *and* answered the question as originally written is harsh. It's the OP's fault for not being clear, not the answerer's. That said, leave a comment explaining it and give them time to update their answer.

If the edit significantly changed the scope of the question and would've required a non-trivial effort on the answerer's part to update, then rollback the edit and ask the OP to post a new question.

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear. Read. Whatever. Thanks!

Comment: @Slanec, another solution is to edit the answer to add a warning that it was for a previous version of the question. Leaving it just in a comment is risky, as people may not read it.