# My answer asking for clarification was removed 

Tags: support

I left a comment on the Stack Overflow question *[Connect to Skype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824400/)* asking for clarification, but this was removed because it's not an answer.

I was told what not to do, but I wasn't informed how I could/should make a comment. I am the Skype developer community manager and am looking to engage with the developers' questions.

What can I do?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand a thing. 1) Which comment? 2) What do you mean by `red`? 3) What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Dennis He posted a comment as an answer and it was deleted, so it now appears in red.

Comment: Not sure this deserves a downvote - this is someone who was just looking to help someone with his product, so it's not surprising he doesn't know all the nuances of how the SO system works.

Comment: @AnnaLear: That explains a lot.

Comment: @JNK: I didn't downvote, but the tooltip **does** say *This question [...] is unclear [...]*. Now that it's edited, reversing might be in order.

Comment: No I didn't appreciate the difference between answers & comments as used here. Back the Skype forum you just post away then, hopefully, the user marks the most helpful post as a solution.. Thanks for all the help guys

Comment: @AllenSmith: it's best not to think of StackExchange as a forum. If you do, you'll likely be disappointed.

Comment: I've upvoted one of your other answers, so you now have enough reputation to write comments.

Answer (score 17):

Check out the comment Kev left for you on your post:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you've earned 50 rep you'll be able to leave comments on any post, in the meantime please don't use answers for this purpose.

You have to earn 50 reputation before you're able to leave comments. Until then, using answers instead isn't acceptable and such posts will be removed.

The easiest way to earn reputation is to find some questions to answer that don't require clarification. You should get 50 in no time. :)

(As a side note, asking for clarification on a question that's almost 3 years old may be a lost cause anyway.)

Answer (score 9):

Until you hit 50 rep you can't leave comments (except on your own posts).

This does not mean it's OK to post an answer that is really a comment.

To get 50 rep, you can:

- Make suggested edits on posts that need improvement
- Post good answers
- Post good questions
- Earn a bounty
- A bunch of other things

[See also this canonical question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)