# Reputation Levels

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, privileges

I can't figure out why with my measly 38 reputation I can post answer, but not comments. Very often I find a point that should go in a comment, since it's not an actual answer, but either have to pass the question by since what I have to write isn't "answery" enough or post an answer which is really a comment in disguise.

I'm thinking this maybe backwards or part of the 'suppress the chit-chat' methodology of StackOverflow.

So, to make this a question. Why can I post answers but not comments?

Comment: You can't comment below `x` rep ?? [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) says otherwise.

Comment: I can comment here and I'm below 50.

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk that is on meta, on SO the [privilege of commenting everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) isn't until 50 rep

Comment: @TronicZomB Obviously... thanks.

Comment: This is a terrible inconsistency and should be fixed. I propose that nobody is allowed to do anything on this site until they have reached 50 reputation points.

Comment: @user414076 I propose that we set all reputation back to 1 for all users, so every can't start getting reputation.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk'sSock You're welcome :)

Comment: @user414076 This ! Jon skeet would probably find a way to earn rep anyway.

Comment: See also: [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design in order to keep the signal to noise ratio high. Some, not all, low rep users do not fully comprehend the methodology of the Stack Exchange sites. If low rep users were allowed the privilege of commenting everywhere then higher rep users would be spending more of their time cleaning up noise that could have been prevented (as it is now) instead of contributing in other meaningful ways.

The Stack Exchange sites are not meant to be forums for discussion like so many other sites, it is meant for questions and their answers, that is it. Comments are meant to be cleaned up by their owner (usually, though it seems not everyone does, including myself at times) once the discussion is done; put relevant parts into the answer and remove the noise.

Comment: It's also spam deterrent.

Answer (score 4):

Most users, that only ask questions, will not need the [*comment everywhere*](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) feature. Everyone can comment on its own posts and everywhere in own questions.
To avoid that inexperienced users write useless comments everywhere there is this restriction.

At the very beginning it is a bit of a pain when you want to participate in a question and are not allowed to ask for clarification. But you need only 50 rep to comment everywhere, if you participate regularly and seriously, then you will reach this threshold very quick.

Comment: Also note that answers bump a post, so it will reviewed (And there is the First Post review queue), which is not the case with comments. So no one sees the spam except Google.