# Enhance the visibility of commenting rules for new users

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, privileges, disputed-flags

It is very clear know that low-reps users understand the comment privilege exist and they don't have it in the beggining...

*However it is not clear it is about commenting in general and not the privilige.*

It leads to things like **comments written inside answers**, because they still want to comment without the privilege.
It unneedlessly poullute the flagging list and lead to confusion *(for example, [I flagged this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22872979/2284570) and I got the flag disputed)*.

I think there would be less things like this if rules were clarified on that point...

Comment: Clearer how? Any suggestions?

Comment: @juergend : By simply tell them in the rules, that, if they don't have the comment privilege, this is not to prevent them from writing anything which is realted to commenting, and no just the privilege itself...

Comment: Well, if the prompt you get when you try to post a comment without the rep does not *already* say it, it could say "*DO NOT POST YOUR COMMENT AS AN ANSWER!". An icon of the skull and bones next to it would be a nice touch.

Comment: @Louis : I would rather put this inside the answer section, because they can write comments inside answer without having tried to comment before...

Comment: Er... I find the current title of this question to be suggesting an incorrect remedy: "Tell new users the commenting privilege is about the right to commment in general, and not just the privilege". The low rep users who post comments as answers are doing something which would be *just as incorrect* for someone who has the privilege of posting comments. Nobody, **irrespective of reputation or privileges**, is allowed to post comments as answers. This is the message that must be conveyed.

Comment: @Louis : So please edit the question and I'll accept the change... Because I' don't have a real idea on how this  question should be wrote.

Comment: @Louis : No I'm just saying I won't reject it... **Please edit it!**

Answer (score 3):

This is already implemented:[image: meta]

The real problem is that people just don't read.

Comment: No, When you read this for the first time (including me), I didn't thought about the comment privilige. So many user write: Sorry I would have used a comment if I could.

Comment: That's why I would add a third line **IN BOLD** under `"But avoid"` which would tell `"Commenting: You need to get and use the comment privilege first if you want to comment"`

Comment: @user commenting usualy involves: asking for help,clarification and responding to other answers

Comment: Yes, so replacing this line look a good idea...

Comment: @user the problem isn't about the sentence it is just that some people don't read. Unfortunatly we can't do anything about it

Comment: So, I think it could be repeated with the message they got when they try to comment without the privilege... because it seems that one is well understood (They know comments exists). I didn't make the link to the commenting privilige when I read this for the first time... It thinks they really read the message, but they don't pay the attention it require, So it would be really efficient if it written more clearly.

Comment: @user2284570 many users give real answers and for them any extra line is just noise. I don't think it's good idea to add that noise just for the slim chance it will prevent few bad answers. The loss (people who will get frustrated over this) is greater than the gain.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : I am not necessary thinking to adding lines... I'm thinking on how to get things clearer. The question is: how to make understand the commenting right as well as the commenting privilege? (users understand well the reason they don't have the comment privilige).

Comment: @user2284570 I fear there isn't such a way. As the answer here says, most people won't read anyway so having them learn the hard way (post comment as answer, having it downvoted/deleted) is about the only possible way to make them understand.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : That's why I suggest to change this message: "**Commenting requires an account with 50 reputation**" to "**This is a privilege which requires an account with 50 reputation. Please do no try to comment using other methods such as using answers for commenting**". Since this message seems to be well-read and understood. Please note this is not [lowering the required reputation.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12119/242800 "Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment")

Comment: @user2284570 fair enough, better edit the question to reflect this request. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard : This was just a suggestion. I'm thinking, the rule in the answer section ("asking for help,clarification and responding to other answers") would be better if it would contain the word in bold: **COMMENTING**. I've poor efficient ideas, that's why I'm asking for a solution in an anwser (let other peoples do better)... In fact the answer could became an another feature-request.

Comment: @user2284570 so change the tag to [meta-tag:discussion] to reflect this, since feature request questions are expected to suggest some, well, feature request. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard : DONE! I used the `"feature-request"` tag because several question like this are answered by a staff-member who implment his answer directly...

Answer (score 1):

Most users would first try to add a comment and there is written you need a minimum rep of 50 what is clear enough in my opinion. Of course only if you've been on stackoverflow before.

The word "rep" should may be a hyperlink leading to a explanation of what rep is.