# Suggestions to replace 50rep-barrier

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, privileges, spam

New users have to get 50 reputation points to be able to comment. I disagree with this design choice, because:

- If you are mostly just reading instead of writing, it takes ages to get 50 reputation, even if you are a normal, non-spammy person.
- If you find an answer that you can't execute because you don't fully understand it, you can't comment to ask a clarifying question. You could create a completely new question, but a question like "how to execute that answer" is not what is wanted here and often it's so specific that it's not worth its own question.
- To get 50 reputation you mostly have to put a lot of effort into this site, either by going through 25 questions and answers and make some grammar corrections or similar or you have to find an unanswered question that you know the answer to and that still gets enough attention for 5 votes or you have to ask a question which is considered good, so you have to not only have (or invent?) a problem, but do research for it before asking, word it properly, etc.
- If you just found a SE question using Google and quickly want to ask a clarifying question, you can't. Nobody bothers putting all this effort into a random Q&A website just to be able to write a little comment.
- If you quickly need to do something and the only good solution is here, but you want to ask a clarifying question, you can't do it in time.
- The fact that commenting requires a higher reputation than asking, answering or editing obviously leads to new users using those as replacements. That's obviously not wanted, but if that's the only way for them to express themselves, they do it.

Stack Exchange is made to help people and if you can't comment because of missing reputation, but you have to, you are left "helpless".

So I propose some solutions. They can each stand alone or be used together. Maybe using all three would be the best.

- **Limited visiblity**: Comments by sub-50s could only be visible for users who have either 1K+ (or another limit) reputation or have participated in that post (question or answer) by posting, editing or commenting on it. Of course that wouldn't prevent new users from spamming those, but at least it affects less people. I would say that's still better than just disallowing them completely. If only these people get notified, you can already contact the ones you want to reach in most cases.
- **A new review queue**: It could be called "Comments by new users" and would contain these comments either before or after they become publicly readable. Of course this would not work well on large sites, but on the other ones it can work. And since comments are shorter than most questions and answers, they can be checked faster. The usual "me too" or "thanks" comments can be filtered out extremely quickly.
- **A smart filter**: This would of course take some development time, but there could be a filter like there already is for "low quality posts". Everything that doesn't get picked up by this filter could be posted, everything else not. It would probably have to be a bit more strict than the "low quality post" filter to avoid intelligent spam.

And lastly: Don't forget that there is a flag option on comments. That also contributes to avoiding spam.

Of course the 50 reputation barrier can't just be removed on its own, but any of these suggestions alone could already improve the situation and potentially make the 50 reputation barrier redundant so that it could be removed. How it currently is, Stack Exchange is extremely frustrating to get in.

Comment: ... even 25 accepted edits will do. _"you mostly have to put a lot of effort into this site ..."_ C'mon!

Comment: I agree with @Carcigenicate.  In addition, from my experience on Ask Ubuntu, where 99% of comments are irrelevant, offtopic, or complaining about things, lowering the rep barrier or removing it will cause issues and just make more work for moderators.  Even with additional review queues or limited visibility.

Comment: @user0042 Yes, that is much. Imagine programming something, maybe at work, you research something you need, you find an answer fitting, but need a little help to execute it. Now you have to stop your work to put an hour or so into this site just to be able to ask a simple clarification question. How do you explain that to your boss?

Comment: @Thomas Ward Do this comments look like something that could be automatically sorted?

Comment: @Fabian Not sure what you mean by your question, but if you mean "something that could be automatically handled" the answer is "No".  While I'm not at liberty to divulge specifics, I can say that a handful of people have gotten a talking to by myself or other moderators for comments being ranty or rude, and I can also say that 99% of all *answers* I see flagged are otherwise comments that serve no useful purpose and therefore would be nuked anyways.

Answer (score 19):

> The fact that commenting requires a higher reputation than asking, answering or editing obviously leads to new users using those as replacements. That's obviously not wanted

That's *exactly* what is wanted.

- A related question posted in a comment below an answer may easily never see a response if the author is long gone / busy / doesn't remember / doesn't know. A new question can be found and answered by anyone with the skill to do so.
- A new answer posted as a comment can only be edited for a few minutes, can't be searched for, won't sort with other answers, and cannot readily contain very many details. A new answer - even if just a guess - can be edited, improved, commented on, and voted on according to its actual utility to other readers.
- Moderation tools for questions and answers are far, far superior to those available for comments. Yes, we could build lots of additional tooling for comment moderation (as you suggest), but that's work that could be better put toward making the tools available for questions and answers *even better*.

Ultimately, these are Q&A sites not comment sites. The focus is supposed to be on **q**uestions and **a**nswers. The fact that comments exist *at all* is a concession to the need for some form of out-of-band communication, but at best it is barely tolerated.

#### Related:

- [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)
- [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment)

Comment: My main example are clarifying questions, not guessed answers. How should someone ask them?

Comment: See the first related link I posted, @Fabian. If you want clarity on an answer, post a new question. If you want clarity on a question... Well, either you have a plausible scenario that might explain the problem and you can post an answer, or... Find a different question.

Comment: If it's stuff like "what do you mean with...", you either have to be really lucky that the same person reads it or that someone else happens to know.

Comment: You have to be really lucky for the same person to read it *period* - somewhere north of 60% of all answer authors haven't visited the site recently (and may never visit it again). If you *need* an answer, do you want to bet on one person being around and willing to answer your question, or anyone who happens to be actively looking for answers in that topic?

Comment: Hm... I'll come back here next time I find a good example.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what [Shog wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303281/152859), I think it should be noted that 50 rep is not that much, really. It's just enough that it requires some knowledge of the site to get, but not so much that it requires great investment. If you sit down for an hour and browse the feed, you'll probably find some questions that you can answer. If you write decent answers, each will probably get at least one to two votes, potentially more. You only need five votes.

Comment: An hour is way too much to quickly ask a clarifying question. And as I said, a review queue could only work on smaller sites.

Comment: @Fabian You only need 50 rep once. And if you're going to use the site at all, an hour is not that much time to invest to get around the limit forever. An hour was also arbitrary. It could take less time, or more depending on when you're on. My point was that it's an extremely low hurdle to have to clear, so I don't think it's worth it to start changing things just to get around that.

Comment: @fabian and that is the problem, you don't want to put in effort or contribute to a site, you just want people like me to spend time and effort, more than one hour, answering your questions, voluntarily and for free. Give and take, 50 rep is nothing compared to the effort required to answer questions. If you don't want to pay that very small price, then Yahoo or Quora will answer your questions but without any quality standards.